# Get Python Discord Bot to DM Hardcoded recipient the Name of the person that joined

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have done some research and I know to use `on_member_join()` to know when a user joins the server. But I am having a hard time finding out how to get the username of that user and send a message to my personal account with that username. The reason for this is because my discord server is fairly small, and I get new users every day, only I want to get notified of this that way I can personally talk to them when they join.

Comment: Please include a [mre] of your attempt at meeting the requirement described (grabbing the username of the new joiner) along with a succinct explanation of where in that attempt you’re getting stuck. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the Member object by referencing it in the function definition. [Link to the Discord.py reference of the on_member_join event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join). After that you can just use something like the fetch_user("your personal ID") method and send to your dm the member.user.

Example Code:

```py
    import discord
    # Starting the client with all Intents so you can use the on_member_join() event.
    Client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

    @Client.event
    def on_member_join(member):
      your_user = Client.fetch_user("your id")
      your_dm = await your_user.dm_channel
      # Verify if there is already a DM, otherwise create the channel
      if not your_dm:
        your_dm = await your_user.create_dm()
      await your_dm.send(member.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable the `members` intents by putting the following code as your bot definition:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

# If you're using discord.Client():
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
# If you're using commands.Bot():
client = commands.Bot(options_here,intents=intents)
```

After this, you can send a DM to a user object like a channel and use `member.user` to get the new member's name:

```
def on_member_join(member):
    dmUser = await client.fetch_user(579450993167564811)
    await dmUser.send(member.user) # Sends member's name to dmUser via DM
```